# Dynamic number of series in Excel Scatter Plot

Tags: excel, vba, scatter-plot, dynamically-generated

I have a data set (2 tables see first screenshot below) which dynamically update both by the rows and columns - and used that to plot XY Scatter, (x values are pulled by the table above, and y values from the table below).

There are 18 series in all, i.e. devices starting from CPAP to X-Ray Machine.

[image: First Screenshot - dataset]

Each series has a dynamic range using the OFFSET function and hence that updating does not give an error on the chart - BUT because the devices itself are dynamic, they can either be only 1 series or all 18 series. When that updates, it results an error on the scatter plot. (see 2nd screenshot).

[image: Blanks show up in series and that returns an error message]

As you can see from the 2nd screenshot, the series become blanks and returns an error. I want the chart to reflect only that series that are not blanks.

I have a basic understanding of VBA, and so couldnt figure out how to code that functionality in the chart based on the searches I made to find a solution. Would appreciate if someone can help me figure this code!

edit:

[image]

Attached is a screenshot with just one device selection (i.e. Pulse Oximeter).

The formula for X values is:

```
=OFFSET(TDI!$B$12,0,0,1,COUNT(TDI!$12:$12)-1)
```

and for Y values:

```
=OFFSET(TDI!$B$36,0,0,1,COUNT(TDI!$36:$36))
```

Comment: Can you provide a dataset with only one device? As well as the formula that you mention (the one with `OFFSET`)

Comment: Thanks Peh. I've replied to your query with a screenshot and formula below.